# Generate SQL query for one-to-many relation

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
Actual Result: 
[ 
    { id: 1, title: 'Test Tournament #$1', d_title: 'Rendering Vue Slots content to an iframe'},
    { id: 1, title: 'Test Tournament #$1', d_title: 'Example' },
    { id: 1, title: 'Test Tournament #$1', d_title: 'Example' },
    { id: 1, title: 'Test Tournament #$1', d_title: 'asdfasdf' },
    { id: 2, title: 'Test Tournament #$2', d_title: 'Rendering Vue Slots content to an iframe'},
    { id: 2, title: 'Test Tournament #$2', d_title: 'Example' },
    { id: 2, title: 'Test Tournament #$2', d_title: 'Example' },
    { id: 2, title: 'Test Tournament #$2', d_title: 'asdfasdf' } 
]

Expected Result: 
[ 
    { id: 1, title: 'Test Tournament #$1', detail: 
        [
             { d_title: 'Rendering Vue Slots content to an iframe'},
             { d_title: 'Example'},
             { d_title: 'Example'},
             { d_title: 'asdfasdf'},
        ]
    },
    { id: 2, title: 'Test Tournament #$2', detail: 
        [
              { d_title: 'Rendering Vue Slots content to an iframe'},
              { d_title: 'Example'},
              { d_title: 'Example'},
              { d_title: 'asdfasdf'},
        ]
    }
]
```

How do I obtain the 'Expected Result' by using SQL queries?

In Laravel, we can obtain it by using the relation with table but how do I get it with pure SQL queries?

Comment: if you like to use foreach loop i can suggest you an answer ?

Comment: yes i would like to know your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot get directly this result, you need to make it manually,

1- first get just tile & id then loop it. and run second query which brings d_title. in that way you can get your desire output format.

2- other way is to get your all required data with order by and then loop it and make a desire output format.

laravel also take 1st way to do this. now its up to you what you want to do.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion actually i know both way but i thought if there is any sql query that might help to generate the expected result by one single sql command.


and also in 1st method suppose if there are thousands of data then we will need to make the request many times so i was wondering if any sql query to generate the expected result is available.

Thanks

Comment: yes, mysql did not support these kind of queries, but in oracle we can do that. in one query. :)

Comment: around 90% of time we do pagination so no worries if you have thousands of records. for rest of 10% 2nd option is good

Answer (score 0):

if your array like this

```
$ActualResult = 
[ 
    { id: 1, title: 'Test Tournament #$1', d_title: 'Rendering Vue Slots content to an iframe'},
    { id: 1, title: 'Test Tournament #$1', d_title: 'Example' },
    { id: 1, title: 'Test Tournament #$1', d_title: 'Example' },
    { id: 1, title: 'Test Tournament #$1', d_title: 'asdfasdf' },
    { id: 2, title: 'Test Tournament #$2', d_title: 'Rendering Vue Slots content to an iframe'},
    { id: 2, title: 'Test Tournament #$2', d_title: 'Example' },
    { id: 2, title: 'Test Tournament #$2', d_title: 'Example' },
    { id: 2, title: 'Test Tournament #$2', d_title: 'asdfasdf' } 
];
```

use this foreach

```
    $response = [];
    foreach($ActualResult as $result)
    {
      $response[$result['id']][$result['title']] = $result['d_title'];
    }
   dd($response);
```